# Angular/AngularJS application dependency injection only works with @Inject() decorators

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

We have a large AngularJS application that we're in the process of upgrading to Angular using the NgUpgrade module. Everything works reasonably well, but one thing we're noticing is that Angular dependency injection doesn't seem to work as well as it does in a 'native Angular' application.

For instance, when we create a component that has a constructor like this:

```js
constructor(readonly fb: FormBuilder) {
    // fb is undefined here
}
```

Then the FormBuilder can for some reason not be resolved. If however we create the constructor like this:

```js
constructor(@Inject(FormBuilder) readonly fb: FormBuilder) {
    // fb is an instance of the FormBuilder here
}
```

Then the property is properly injected. I realise this isn't much to go on, and as it is a very large application I'm sure we have something setup incorrectly, but since the dependency can be resolved when using the `@Inject()` decorator there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the injector itself.

Any pointers as to where to look further would be greatly appreciated. We're using the latest Angular version (11.x).

Edit:

We don't use the Angular CLI (not sure if that would even work with the NgUpgrade module). We use a fairly standard Webpack build to bundle the javascript. To bootstrap the app, we use the following code:

```js
// Bootstrap using the UpgradeModule
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
    const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
    upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
})
```

Edit 2:

We're using this webpack.config.js file to bundle the application

```js
// If you are using https then at the start include ‘fs’
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

//requiring indirect packages, so that the npm-check sees it as an used package
const cssLoader = require('css-loader');
const exposeLoader = require('expose-loader');
const htmlLoader = require('html-loader');
const nodeSass = require('node-sass');
const sassLoader = require('sass-loader');
const rawLoader = require('raw-loader');
const lessLoader = require('less-loader');
const fileLoader = require('file-loader');
const styleLoader = require('style-loader');
const webpackCli = require('webpack-cli');
const webpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const lodash = require('lodash');

const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { CheckerPlugin } = require('awesome-typescript-loader');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const bundleFileName = 'bundle';
const dirName = 'wwwroot/dist';
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    var config = {
        mode: "development",
        entry: [
            './src/app/main.ts',
            './src/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.less',
            './src/css/styles.less',
            './src/css/themes.less',
            './src/css/utility.less',
            './src/css/widgets.less',
            './src/css/animate.css'
        ],
        output: {
            filename: '[name].[contenthash:8].js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, dirName),
            publicPath: '',
            pathinfo: false
        },
        resolve: {
            // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as a resolvable extension.
            extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                    test: require.resolve("jquery"),
                    loader: "expose-loader",
                    options: {
                        exposes: ["$", "jQuery"]
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    loader: "awesome-typescript-loader"
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        'css-loader',
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(s[c|a]ss)$/,
                    use: [
                        'to-string-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                esModule: false
                            }
                        },
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.less$/,
                    use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        'css-loader',
                        'less-loader'
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    loader: "html-loader"
                },
                {
                    test: /.(png|jpg|ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader'
                }
            ]
        },
        optimization: {
            moduleIds: 'deterministic',
            runtimeChunk: 'multiple',
            splitChunks: {
                chunks: 'all',
                maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
                minSize: 0,
                //maxSize: 1024 * 1024,
                cacheGroups: {
                    vendor: {
                        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                        priority: 100,
                        name(module) {
                            // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
                            // or node_modules/packageName
                            const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];

                            // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
                            return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
                        },
                    },
                    libs: {
                        test: /[\\/]src[\\/]libincludes[\\/]/,
                        priority: 50,
                        name(module) {
                            return 'libincludes';
                        },
                    },
                    app: {
                        test: /[\\/]Project[\\/]src[\\/]app[\\/]/,
                        priority: 40,
                        name(module) {
                            // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
                            // or node_modules/packageName
                            const match = module.context.match(/[\\/]Project[\\/]src[\\/]app[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/);
                            const packageName = (match && match.length) ?
                                match[1] :
                                "common";

                            // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
                            return `app.${packageName}`;
                        },
                    },
                },
            }
        },
        performance: {
            hints: "warning",
            maxAssetSize: 1024 * 1024,
            maxEntrypointSize: 1024 * 1024
        },
        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin({
                dry: false,
                dangerouslyAllowCleanPatternsOutsideProject: true
            }),
            new CheckerPlugin(),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: bundleFileName + '.css'
            }),
            new CopyWebpackPlugin({
                patterns: [
                    { from: 'src/lib', to: 'lib' },
                    { from: 'src/css', to: 'css' },
                    { from: 'src/images', to: 'images' }
                ]
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: 'src/index.html', cache: false })
        ]
    };
    return config;
};
```

Comment: it is being done by angular compiler. do you use anything else, before applyting the compiler itself?

Comment: Thanks @Andrei I've edited the question with more information on how we build and bootstrap the application.

Comment: webpack config is important in this issue

Comment: I assume your are not using angular compiler at all. it it possible to setup your application ini a way that it would use static angular compiler, and then - being run with `platformBrawser()`, not `platformBrowserDynamic()`? it would also improve your application startup time

Comment: @Andrei I've added the webpack config, but since there's little information on how to properly use Angular without the CLI (which afaik can't be used with the NgUpgrade module) we're kinda winging it...

Comment: if this auto injecting feature and startup performance of your app are important of the project, then you will have to apply angular compiler plugin for your app. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack here is the package with compiler

Comment: Thanks @Andrei that looks promising, I'm gonna look into that!